# store file tree in .apk

Tags: android, apk

How can I store a normal tree of files inside an Android .apk without all the weirdness of the Ressource or Asset concepts? It seems I have to do some akward thing to use Files from current path like any non-Android Java application do?

Comment: Have you tried just to copy your file tree into the android project? (not res, not assets)

Comment: as far as I see those files are not incooperated into the .apk by the default build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I haven't tested this, but a solution could be to add extra files to the APK before signing. You could automate this from the command line:

```
$ ant release
$ zip -r bin/MyApp-unsigned.apk <custom_folder>
$ jarsigner -verbose -keystore <keystore> -storepass <password> bin/MyApp-unsigned.apk <alias>
$ zipalign -v 4 bin/MyApp-unsigned.apk bin/MyApp-signed.apk
```

And then, in your activity, open the APK with ZipFile to access your custom folder:

```
ZipFile apk = new ZipFile(getApplicationInfo().sourceDir);
```

I'm not sure how the Android Market would react to this non-standard APK though.

Comment: At least, the ZipFile interface works to access the .apk contents. I think I give in now and rename my files according to the crude assets/ naming rules, to prevent this custom build process you propose.

Answer (score 2):

"use Files from current path" and "store... inside an Android .apk file" have nothing to do with each other.

Since, statistically speaking, you are likely familiar with Windows, let's draw some analogies.

"store... inside an Android .apk file" on Windows would be "store... inside a Windows .exe file". This is reasonably uncommon on Windows, at least the last I checked.

"use Files from current path" on Windows would refer to files that perhaps exist in the app's `Program Files` directory or the equivalent. On Android, this works fairly conventionally -- use `getFilesDir()` and Java file I/O.

What exists in Windows and does not exist in Android is the concept of packaging files to be installed at install time via an installer package, such as a `.msi` file.

Since you declined to tell us what the "normal tree of files" is and why you think it should be "inside an Android .apk", it is impossible to give you advice on how to avoid whatever "weirdness" you think exist in the "Ressource [sic] or Asset concepts". All I can tell you is that the equivalent on other OSes to bake files into the executable would likely be similarly "weird".

Comment: I am aware of the fact that the .apk is an archived file, but I wonder why it has to lack the ability to store a "ususal" folder tree inside for later use. That makes portability of existing applications very hard. Using the default android build system, its even inferior to the capabilities of a simple .zip / .jar archive, for example filenames in "assets/" apply to many unusual constraints.

Answer (score 0):

With assets you can have a file tree in an APK, which can be accessed by using the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) returned by [getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets%28%29).

The whole point of this mechanism is saving space. The files are not extracted to the file system when the app gets installed. When you read the content of an asset, it is uncompressed (unzipped) on the fly from the APK. It does make sense. Saving space is important on Android devices.

But nothing forbids you to extract the assets tree into the file system when your application is first launched, if you need that.

Comment: But remember, if you extract the files, you will be wasting twice the space.

Comment: Right, and it also requires some extra error checking at first launch, to gracefully handle the case where there isn't enough space to extract the tree.

Comment: As I commented above, the assets/ folder applies unusual constraints to files, eg. the filename charset is restricted, there are reports that files cannot exceed 1mb in size and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work for you is to open the APK using [ZipFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) and [ZipEntry](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html), as this gives you access very similar to a conventional read-only directory structure.

Alternatively, you may be able to use [getResourceAsStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to work with a traditional file structure - you might find [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/microemu/issues/detail?id=27) useful if you go with this approach - it shows some perils of working with [getResourceAsStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) on android.

I should add that you shouldn't think of an APK as something gets extracted - files inside the APK are not on the filesystem, they're like resources inside a JAR file in a J2ME or J2SE environment (or the WAR/EAR for J2EE).

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello